# retrieving data from mysql blob charset error

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, mysqli, blob

I am retrieving some data from a mysql table. One field contains blobs. I have tried to retrive data several ways, like including `SET NAMES 'utf8'`, `SET CHARSET 'utf8'`, selecting the field as it is and like this too: `CAST(description AS CHAR(10000) CHARACTER SET utf8`. The text I want to get has romanian characters, and for situation to situation, depending whether I include SET NAMES and etc, I get some characters but not: ă and ș. How come it is working for î for ex. If I run the query in phpMyAdmin characters are returned correctly, but not when running from php and var_dump-ing the field. Any ideea where I made a mistake?

Comment: If phpMyAdmin works fine, are you sure the encoding of your page is correct?

Comment: I am retrieving that data from a remote DB and inserting into a local one. As soon as data is inserted it has character errors, I can see that checking in the local db with phpmyadmin

Comment: Even stranger that with the "wrongly formatted" data being inserted, when I retrieve it locally and set encoding with mozilla addon it shows up correctly, but not on website. Both mozilla forced encoding and website page encoding are utf8

Comment: how do you show the data on you php page...are you tried to use utf8_encode or utf8_decode php functions on you datafield??

Comment: tried after reading your suggestion. It get`s even worse introducing that white question marks with black background